# Set items in table java web scraping

Tags: java, jsoup

Okey so my problem is next: I use web scraping to take some data from web page IMDB in this case, that data is titles of movies, and I already tried to print it in console and that works fine. My problem is that I can not save that titles in my table columns, I put all needed codes for this problem, and I cant find where I made mistake and why titles wont show in table columns. At the and, user need to pick one title and that title need to be stored in text field. Have someone any idea, please?

I have table:

```
TableColumn izborAuta = new TableColumn("Izbor auta");
TableColumn lokacijaPreuzimanja = new TableColumn("Lokacija 
preuzimanja");
TableColumn lokacijaVracanja = new TableColumn("Lokacija Vracanja");
TableColumn cena = new TableColumn("Cena");
```

I have this code to setup columns:

```
izborAuta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vozila, String> 
("izborAuta"));
lokacijaPreuzimanja.setCellValueFactory(new 
PropertyValueFactory<Vozila, String>("lokacijaPreuzimanja"));
lokacijaVracanja.setCellValueFactory(new 
PropertyValueFactory<Vozila, String>("lokacijaVracanja"));
cena.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vozila, String> 
("cena"));
tableView.setItems(Baza.baza.prikazBaze());
tableView.getColumns().addAll(izborAuta, lokacijaPreuzimanja, 
lokacijaVracanja, cena);
```

I have this code, so when I pick one item from table that item need to be stored in textField:

```
tableView.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
    Vozila v = (Vozila) 
    tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    txIzborAuta.setText(v.getIzborAuta());
    txLokacijaPreuzimanja.setText(v.getLokacijaPreuzimanja());
    txLokacijaVracanja.setText(v.getLokacijaVracanja());
    txCena.setText(v.getCena());
});
```

And at the end I use web scraping to save items in table:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top? 
ref_=nv_mv_250").get();
Elements elems = doc.select("table.chart.full-width");
for (Element e : elems) {
    String izborAuta = e.select(".titleColumn").text();
    String lokacijaPreuzimanja = e.select(".titleColumn").text();
    String lokacijaVracanja = e.select(".titleColumn").text();
    String cena = e.select(".titleColumn").text();
    Vozila v = new Vozila();
    v.setIzborAuta(izborAuta);
    v.setLokacijaPreuzimanja(lokacijaPreuzimanja);
    v.setLokacijaVracanja(lokacijaVracanja);
    v.setCena(cena + " " + "RSD");
    Baza.insertVozila(v);
}
```

Comment: Are you working with jfx?

Comment: Yes. I have some textFields, labels, button and that table.